# Observable object in template calls api twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

Example code:

```
  public settings$: Observable<
    SettingsResponse
  > = this._service.getSettings().pipe();
```

Then in template I use:

```
{{ (settings$ | async)?.id }}
{{ (settings$ | async)?.config }}
```

This does two calls to api. How can I do it with observable and only have 1 call?

Answer (score 1):

Add in the `shareReplay(1)` operator into your pipe:

```
public settings$: Observable<SettingsResponse> = this._service.getSettings().pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
);
```

This caches the most recent value and provides it to all subscribers, including late subscribers. If you don't want late subscribers to get the most recent value and to only get values as they come in, use the `share` operator.

More details [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay).

Comment: This still creates multiple subscriptions and requires safe navigation which is unnecessary as angular has a dedicated keyword for this. The template would be a mess, code would be duplicated, the safe navigation operator is required everywhere, this is an anti-pattern

Comment: I still prefer this over *ngIf as that necessitates an alternate code block for when it's false. But that's just my preference. This is the first I've ever heard of it being an anti-pattern.

Comment: So you use 20 `async` pipes when the settings object has 20 settings properties? Is this what your templates look like? `{{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }}{{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.id }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.config }} {{ (settings$ | async)?.id }}`

Answer (score 1):

The `as` keyword along with the `*ngIf` operator can be used to capture the result of the `async` pipe to be used in the rest of the template. Add it to a parent tag or `ng-container` if you don't want to introduce any more elements to the dom.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="settings$ | async as settings"> // <-- or div
  {{ settings.id }}
  {{ (settings.config }}
</ng-container>
```

It is documented here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable